# Blank White page React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-start

I am currently using a create reactjs app with `localhost:3000` as the server. I have added a `Header.js` page and linked it to my App.js but a blank white page keeps showing up when I run my deployment server. The program is reading my index.js file linked to my app.js because a `serviceworker.js` syntax shows up as it couldn't compile, but it still leaves a white page. Below is my code.

App.Js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <h1>This is a tinder clone</h1>

     {/* Header */}
     <Header />
     {/* Tinder Cards */ }
    {/* Buttons below tinder card */}

    {/* Chats screen */}
    {/* Indvidual chat screen */}

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Header.css';
import PersonIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Person';
import QuestionAnswerIcon from '@mui/icons-material/QuestionAnswer';

function Header() {
    return (
        // BEM 
        <div className="header">
        <PersonIcon />
        <img src="./images/Ringheart.png" alt="Heart logo"/>
         <QuestionAnswerIcon />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

The error I keep getting in my console is:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 8:0-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './serviceWorker' in 'C:\Users\donal\Videos\Web-Developement\tinder-clone\src'
resolve './serviceWorker' in 'C:\Users\donal\Videos\Web-Developement\tinder-clone\src'
  using description file: C:\Users\donal\Videos\Web-Developement\tinder-clone\package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: C:\Users\donal\Videos\Web-Developement\tinder-clone\package.json (relative path: ./src/serviceWorker)
```

I have also a `"main": "src/app.js"`in my package.json

Comment: That usually happens when there's an error. Open the browser console (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J`) and paste the error in your edited question. I do see invalid syntax in line 8 of `Header.js`. Looks like you know how to write comments in React, and that's not the way; it'll throw a "cannot have multiple elements" error thing.

Comment: I have posted it, and removed the comment from my Header.js, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: That one's easy. You deleted `serviceWorker.js`, so all you have to do is remove everything in your code that has to do with the service worker (lines **5** and **10** in `index.js`).

Comment: I see I got it, just as you commented, thank you, it is working fine now!